# Firebase Cannot receive notification in UK

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2

My application built from IONIC2 with FCM plugin. Everything seem work fine until we have test in UK. All devices can receive push notification with same topics channel except the devices in UK. Then I tried to sent broadcast message via firebase console ,all devices (include the devices in UK) had received push notification.

**nofication json**

`{
    "to" : "/topics/xxx",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "xxx",
      "title" : "xxx"
    },
    "data" : {
      "xxx" : "xxx",
      "xxx" : "xxx"
    }
}`